# Color Bitmap file to Black and White

Tags: c++, c, bitmap

I need to convert a color Bitmap file to Black and White.

I understand that When i read a row of pixels it needs to divide by 4. First question, why? :)

If it doesn't divide by 4, i need to add zeros up until it does.

The major issue i'm having trouble with is reading those zeros. Can anyone tell me how to read those zeros?

Also, if there is a guide anywhere i'd love to see it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The division is used to align each line of the image on a specific boundry, in this case 32 bits. You can determine the number of extra bytes at the end of each line using modulo math.

```
int zero_padding_count = image->actual_width_in_bytes % 4;
```

This will result in a value between 0 and 3. To process then you can do something like this.

```
char *source = image->buffer;
char *dest = some_buffer;

for(int row = 0; row < image->actual_height; row++)
{
    for(int column = 0; column < image->actual_width_in_bytes; column++)
    {
        // do your conversion here
        *source++ = dest++;
    }
    // Now adjust the source pointer for the number of padding bytes at the end
    // of the line
    source += zero_padding_count;
}
```

Comment: does the pixels needs to be decided by 4 or the bit amount (24 bits picture)?

Comment: That depends on how each line of the image is stored in memory. Some libraries don't add padding to the end of each line while others do. You'll need to refer to the appropriate documentation to determine how the size of each line and pixel should be computed. The example I provided is generic, update your question with more specific information and I'll update my answer appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to convert a color image to black and white without performing low-level manipulation, you might want to take a  look at ImageMagick (http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#grayscale).  It has a lot of helpful utilities.